# The improper integral of $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x-1}{ \sqrt[3]{x^5} } dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

I have a kind request to check whether my solution is correct.

$$
\int \limits_{-1}^1 \frac{x-1}{ \sqrt[3]{x^5} } dx = 
\int \limits_{-1}^0 \frac{x-1}{ \sqrt[3]{x^5} } dx  +
\int \limits_{0}^1 \frac{x-1}{ \sqrt[3]{x^5} } dx =
$$ 
$$
=\lim \limits_{A \to 0^+}  \int \limits_{-1}^A \frac{x-1}{ \sqrt[3]{x^5} } dx  +
\lim \limits_{A \to 0^-} \int \limits_{A}^1 \frac{x-1}{ \sqrt[3]{x^5} } dx 
$$

$$
\int \frac{x-1}{\sqrt[3]{x^5}} dx = 3 x^{\frac{1}{3}} - \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}} + C
$$

$$
\int \limits_{-1}^1 \frac{x-1}{ \sqrt[3]{x^5} } dx =
\lim \limits_{A \to 0^+}  \Big{[}3 x^{\frac{1}{3}} - \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}} \Big{]}^{A}_{-1} +
\lim \limits_{A \to 0^-}  \Big{[}3 x^{\frac{1}{3}} - \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}} \Big{]}^{1}_{A} 
$$
$$
\lim \limits_{A \to 0^+} 3 A^{\frac{1}{3}} - \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{A^{\frac{2}{3}}} - \Big{(}3 (-1)^{\frac{1}{3}} - \frac{3}{2}  \frac{1}{ (-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}  } \Big{)} = -\infty
$$

$$
\lim \limits_{A \to 0^-} \frac{3}{2} - 3 A^{\frac{1}{3}} + \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{A^{\frac{2}{3}}} = - \infty
$$

Since:
$$
\lim \limits_{A \to 0+} \frac{1}{A^{\frac{2}{3}}} = \infty
$$
$$
\lim \limits_{A \to 0-} \frac{1}{A^{\frac{2}{3}}} = - \infty
$$

Therefore $\int \limits_{-1}^1 \frac{x-1}{ \sqrt[3]{x^5} } dx$ does not converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct. The oddness of $x^{-5/3}$ does not matter, because
$$\lim_{A \to 0+0} \int_A^1 x^{5/3} \mathrm{d}x$$
is not finite. The same problem appears when you are trying to compute
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 1):

In$$x^{-2/3}-x^{-5/3},$$ the second term is odd and vanishes by symmetry. The first term integrates with exponent $\frac13$, and this converges.

---

Alternatively, set $x:=t^3$, which is invertible.

$$\int \limits_{-1}^1 \frac{x-1}{ \sqrt[3]{x^5} } dx = 3\int \limits_{-1}^1 \left(1-\frac1{t^3}\right)dt.$$

Comment: The second term won't vanish in the case of improper Riemann integral.

Comment: @Botond: the OP is concerned by the Cauchy principal value, isn't he ?

Comment: It looks like a causal improper Riemann integral to me based on the way he computed the integral and the lack of the cauchy-principal-value tag. But if it's a pv integral, then your answer is the correct one. So we would need the confirmation of the op.

Comment: What is OP? It is definitely a causal improper Riemann integral. Nothing fancier.